# Thread 2 received signal SIGBUS

Tags: gdb

> Thread 2 received signal SIGBUS, Bus error. 0x00000001001021e0 in ??
>   ()

. What does this mean? GDB does not specify where this occur either

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> What does this mean?

It means that your program tried to execute instructions at address `0x1001021e0`, but page mapped at that address is not mapped with execute permissions.

> GDB does not specify where this occur either

Yes it *does*: it occurred at address `0x1001021e0`.

What you want to do is:

1. Figure out *how* you got to execute at that address, The GDB `where` command may help
2. Figure out how the page at `0x1001021e0` is mapped. On Linux, `cat /proc/$pid-of-debugged-program/maps` or GDB `info proc maps` should help. Other OSes may have similar facilities.